# spotfire - trying to do kde or just curve the line

Tags: r, spotfire

I'm adding dxp that I currently trying to do kde\curve line,
I've tried to search about it, but can't find answers.
Hope that you would help

thanks in advance!

[This is the file](https://gofile.io/d/5fmvVW)

Comment: What is a kde curve? It is not in spotfire. At least not in my version

Comment: Hi @wannabeDa welcome in our community. I would suggest to be more specific regarding your question. Please remaind to share a reproducible DF

Comment: @phiver kde is Kernel Density Estimation, I thought that maybe someone did it with R in spotfire and could help, if not, I would like to know how to do curve line to smooth the line chart.

Comment: @Borexino thank you! Do you want me to share my csv? and look what I commented to phiver.

Comment: As you prefer. If you want you can simply use ‘dput(head(df)’ or you can produce an example df using R

Comment: @Borexino csv: https://gofile.io/d/LDcWKN